# dashboard - adding, editing and removal

Tags: unity-dash

What are the implications of removing all the partition icons to reduce confusion by 'normal users'. How do you add your own items, folder or drawer. I'm looking to sell my general-business-package across yorkshire. Moving their pc stock onto ubuntu but ensuring they have an easy transition from their current o/s and application.

Comment: Is your question about the Dash (equivalent to windows start menu) or the launcher (equivalent to windows task bar)?

Comment: Dash, the column of icond

Comment: Sorry, column of icons which are on the left and as a column can be configured to only appear when your mouse hovers at the left of the screen

Comment: @user313649 That's called the Launcher.

Answer (score 0):

To remove an icon from the Launcher, just right click on an icon and choose "Unlock from Launcher".

There are two ways to add an icon to the Launcher:

1. Open the program, right click on its icon, and choose "Lock to Launcher"
2. Open the Dash, search for the program, and drag its icon to the Launcher.